# Spring Boot Deployed in Tomcat gives 404 but works Stand-alone

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have been testing Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat for about a month now to build a REST API. Everything was working fine. We now want to deploy the API in a separate development environment which has a couple of other (non-Spring) applications running on a Tomcat container.

I made the changes specified in [Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR using Maven](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/) and [Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging).

The deployment goes well (logs are fine, no errors) and looking at Tomcat management i see my application deployed. However, when I attempt to access http://localhost:8080/sophia/users in curl I get 404.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here are my logs:

Netbeans:

> NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 8.0.17
>       profile mode: false
>       debug mode: false
>       force redeploy: true
>
> In-place deployment at /home/bugz/workspace/pdcore/sophiaserver/target/sophia-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> Deployment is in progress...
>
> deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext1845402702541504208.xml&path=/sophia
>
> OK - Deployed application at context path /sophia
>
> Start is in progress...
>
> start?path=/sophia
>
> OK - Started application at context path /sophia

Tomcat:

> INFO 10:47:52:703 org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/sophia/*]
>
> INFO 10:47:54:042 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Started application in 8.285 seconds (JVM running for 12087.301)
>
> 22-Jan-2015 10:47:54.060 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-99] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /home/bugz/workspace/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/conf/Catalina/localhost/sophia.xml has finished in 12,091 ms

And in sophia.xml for Catalina localhost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="/home/bugz/workspace/pdcore/sophiaserver/target/sophia-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" path="/sophia"/>
```

I've tried accessing

1. http://localhost:8080/sophia/users
2. http://localhost:8080/sophia-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/users (name of WAR)

The first returns a 404 but with the CORS information from my CORS filter bean. The second return 404 without CORS information (which indicates the application has started and is configured but I do not seem to have access to the Controllers).

Comment: Check your logfile, are you sure that the application is deployed at that specific URL...

Comment: @M. Deinum, I've added the logs that I am getting. Controllers are mapped and it seems to be deploying the context as expected (/sophia).

Comment: Your application is mapped to `/sophia`, next your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/sophia/*`, making the URL to call `/sophia/sophia/users`. When running as a jar it is deployed as the root application mapped to `/` ...

Comment: Awesome @M. Deinum, please add an answer to that effect and I will accept. Many thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When running an application the path to call consists of a couple of parts.

The first is the base URL on which the application is deployed, in your case that is `/sophia`.

The second is the servlet mapping of the `DispatcherServlet` in your case that is `/sohpia/*`.

The third is the mapping of the controller inside the `DispatcherServlet`, in your example that is `/users`.

All those things combined create the URL `/sophia/sophia/users`.

The difference between the deployment as a WAR is that you included a separate URL to deploy on, when running as a jar it, by default, is deployed to `/` (the root).

You could fix it by putting `/sophia` as the `server.context-path` in the `application.properties` and map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/*` or `/`. That will in both situations give you the URL you want (and expected).

Comment: When you deploy with an embedded server, it runs without the app name segment.  This detail was my issue.

Answer (score 7):

check java -version means the if you complied war in java 8 and tomcat is running on java 7 then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried extending the SpringBootServletInitializer and overriding the configure method? As stated [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/)

The entry point for jar file is different [Main Class] when compared to running your app as war file inside a container.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

check the java version

version that exists in pom.xml must be the same that the version installed on the server

openjdk 11 works fine for me

https://adoptopenjdk.net/